# Difference of 3 xxx.setAttribute()

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm New to SpringBoot,

I found 3 methods to send parameter from backend to frontend.

java code:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dtbBJVX3jQ/

```
HttpSession.setAttribute()

HttpServletRequest.getServletContext().setAttribute()

WebRequest.setAttribute()
```

Could you tell me what's the difference between 3 `setAttribute()` when in usage?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Read documentation

Comment: It's not just SpringBoot related concept. You need to study JEE (Servlet, JSP) and how these scope are used. You can imagine  Request Scope < Session Scope < Application Scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [HttpSession](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) is part of the Java EE API. It contains session scoped attributes. A session usually spans multiple requests, so whatever you save in a session attribute stays there until the session expires.
- [WebRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequest.html) is a Spring Web abstraction. It allows you to get and set attributes in different scopes (`SCOPE_REQUEST`, `SCOPE_SESSION`). A session-scoped attribute is the same as for `HttpSession`. A request-scoped attribute only lives for the duration of the request.
- [HttpServletRequest.getServletContext().setAttribute()](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) is probably not what you need. `ServletContext` is created only once per web application, so you could only use it to save some global attributes that don't change for different requests.